# How to show that the solution of the following quadratic programming is non-negative

Tags: linear-algebra, nonlinear-programming, quadratic-programming

I have the following quadratic problem:

$max$ $a^Tx+0.5x^TAx$

$s.t:    1^Tx=1$

in which $a=[a_1, a_2,...,a_n]$ is a non-negative vector, and $1^T=[1,1, ..., 1]$. The hessian matrix $A$ has the following structure:
\begin{bmatrix} -n\alpha\beta/a_1&\beta_{12}&\beta_{13}&...&\beta_{1n}\\\beta_{21}&-n\alpha\beta/a_2&\beta_{23}&...&\beta_{2n}\\\beta_{31}&\beta_{32}&-n\alpha\beta/a_3&...&\beta_{3n}\\...&...&...&...&...\\\beta_{n1}&\beta_{n2}&\beta_{n3}&...&-n\alpha\beta/a_n\end{bmatrix}
in which $\alpha=max(a_1,a_2,...,a_n)$ and $\beta=max(\beta_{ij}), i,j=1,...,n$.
Recall that $A$ is symmetric, and $\beta_{ij}=\beta_{ji}$ and that $\beta_{ij}\ge0$.

It follows that $A$ is negative definite; $A$ is an $M$ matrix and $A$ is strictly diagonally dominant matrix. Hence it is guaranteed that $A^{-1}\le0$. From $KKT$ conditions, the optimal solution is as follows:

$$x = (\frac{1^TA^{-1}a+1}{1^TA^{-1}1})A^{-1}1-A^{-1}a\\=\delta x_1+(1-\delta)x_2.$$

where $$x_{1}=\frac{A^{-1}a}{1^TA^{-1}a}$$ and $$x_{2}=\frac{A^{-1}1}{1^TA^{-1}1}$$

in which $\delta =-1^TA^{-1}a\ge0$. When $\delta\le1$ it follows that $x\ge0$. For $\delta>1$, I failed to prove that $x\ge0$. However, as I checked based on hundred thousands of random problem instances, it seems that $x\ge0$ for any value of $\delta$.
Please help me to prove or disprove that $x\ge0$ for any value of $\delta$.
I also could prove the followings that may be useful.

- $\delta = \frac{a^T(x_1-x_2)}{-(x_1-x_2)^TA(x_1-x_2)}$
- $\delta\le\sqrt{(1^TA^{-1}1)(a^TA^{-1}a)}$

Comment: Your question doesn't contain a question mark - could you clarify what you're asking?